# Creating 2D matrix from vector array in javascript. - missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

```
 I am very new in programming and learning javascript. The idea is to create  matrix like 

    0 1 2 3 4
    1 0 1 2 3 
    2 1 0 1 2 
    3 2 1 0 1 
    4 3 2 1 0 

    My edited script looks like this 

var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
var array = [];
for (j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
  {
  for (i=j; i<arr.length; i++)

  {
    array [j][i] = arr [j];
    array [i][j] = arr [j];
  }
}
var arrheight = array [j][i];
var arrwidth = array [i][j];
console.log(arrheight);
console.log(arrwidth)
```

But I am getting this new error "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined". 
What am I doing wrong? I would also love to know alternative and more sophisticated method of producing such matrix.

Comment: the error should include a line number ... by the way ... it's `for` not `For` so that may be your problem - javascript thinks you're trying to run a function like this `functionName(arg1;arg2;arg3)` which is invalid syntax

Comment: Fix the issue with JavaScript being case sensitive. Use semicolons. You do not declare `newarray` anywhere in that code snippet so that will be an issue. And how you are reading the value for `arrheigth` and the `arrwidth` is wrong. And you have a variable `arrweidth` which is mispelled... A lot of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay buddy, here ya go.

```
var linear = [0,1,2,3,4];
var dimensional = [];
var i,j;

for (i=0; i<linear.length; i++) {
    dimensional[i] = []; 
    for (j=0; j<linear.length; j++) {
        dimensional[i][j] = Math.abs(j-i);
    }
}
console.log(dimensional);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming and the Javascript language!

There's a few problems with your code. Your current problem is that you've capitalized the word 'For' -- it should be `for` (note the lowercase. Javascript is case sensitive).

You have not declared your `i` and `j` variables in your for loop. You'll want to declare those like this:

`for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`

Next, you're assigning to the variable newarray without declaring it. You'll want to declare newarray as follows:

`var newarray;`

This should get you started! I highly recommend http://eloquentjavascript.net/ to continue your coding!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. I have fixed for command but I have already declared i and j within the code. However just to clarify my code i delcared j outside the "for" loop as j = 0.
but still i get  " Cannot set property '0' of undefined" for lines 

array2 [j][i] = arr [j];
   array2 [i][j] = arr [j];

How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that for statements are lowercase and JS statements terminate with a semicolon. Also, 'new' is an operator, so I would try to avoid using it.

I'm not sure I'm understanding your objective, but you can build a two dimensional array with the following code:

```
var x = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i] = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
console.log(x);
```

Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I learnt that I can assign 2d square matrix just by Array(number). 
For my objective, I am trying to output
0 1 2 3 4
    1 0 1 2 3 
    2 1 0 1 2 
    3 2 1 0 1 
    4 3 2 1 0 . 
So I probably need to manipulate the code ?